# How do I slant an iphone app screenshot to fit slanted iphone in photoshop/pixelmator?

Tags: iphone, photoshop

I'm trying to put an app screenshot on a slanted picture of the iPhone. How do I slant my screenshot to fit the iPhone screen?

Bonus points if you can explain how to add the reflection as well :)

thank you!

[image]

Comment: Skill, a screenshot and of course Photoshop.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Photoshop, press Command-T. This will put you in Free Transform mode. Then right click on the image you want to slant, and a menu will come up where you clicked. On that menu, you will have options like "Free Transform", "Scale", "Rotate", "Skew", etc. The option you want is "skew". After you click skew, click on the handles on the edge of your image and move your cursor left or right. This will apply a skew transform to your images. Continue to adjust the skew transform with the handles until your photo fits on the iPhone image. For more info on the skew transform, check out this good tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E4HSShiuKNg

P.S. For the reflection, you can create a new layer with a white fill and an opacity gradient, going from around 60% opacity at the top to 0%. Then you can use the marquee tool to cut it into the sheen shape that you want it to be in.

Comment: it is working, but it creates alot of pixellation and wierd distortions to my screenshot, esp since it is text heavy. How do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: @user1337645 Could you save it as a jpeg and post it above so I can see?

Comment: nevermind, it worked great after i clicked save! thanks